# Is the presence of the phase velocity of De-Broglie wave in the Lorentz Transformations a mere coincidence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

We have the term $c^2/v$ in the lorentz transformation for time:
$t' = \gamma (t - x  v/c^2)$. Now, taking into account of the fact that $c^2/v$ is the phase velocity of the De-Broglie wave for a particle with speed v, this reduces to $t' = \gamma (t-t_1)$, and I could explain this term $t_1$ as

> the time taken by a de-broglie wave excited at $x=0$ in the frame $xyzt$ at time $t=0$ to reach the point $x=x$ in the same frame.

But then, during the time special relativity was published, quantum mechanics and the whole idea of de-broglie wave itself didn't exist. (and of course I know de-broglie waves don't really travel thorough real space...)

So my question is how did this rather unusual term turn up in special relativity, whose meaning was understood only 20 years later? I've gone through some textbook derivations of lorentz transformations, but couldn't gather any clue on this seemingly weird connection between relativity and QM.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It actually went the other way around. De Broglie was inspired by the theory of special relativity, (called the restricted theory of relativity at the time).  See page 4 of De Broglie's Nobel prize address[1] for the equation you reference above.

**References**:
De Broglie's Nobel Prize Address
http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1929/broglie-lecture.pdf